Which Stack Exchange website is best for asking questions about wikitext? (wikitext is also known as wiki markup or wikicode)
Which Stack Exchange website is best for asking questions about wikitext? (wikitext is also known as wiki markup or wikicode.)

An example of code written in the wiki-text language is shown below:
{{Speciesbox
 |name=Cat
<!-- There has been extensive discussion about the choice of image in this infobox. Before replacing this image with something else, consider if it actually improves on the ENCYCLOPEDIC CRITERIA that led to this choice. See [[Talk:Cat]] and [[Talk:Cat/Lead photo]] and if in doubt, DISCUSS IT FIRST! -->
 |fossil_range=9,500 years ago – present
 |image={{Multiple image
  |perrow=2/2/2
  |total_width=275
  |image1=Cat August 2010-4.jpg
  |image2=Gustav chocolate.jpg
  |image3=Orange tabby cat sitting on fallen leaves-Hisashi-01A.jpg
  |image4=Siam lilacpoint.jpg
  |image5=Felis catus-cat on snow.jpg
  |image6=Sheba1.JPG
  |border=infobox
  |footer=Various types of cats
}}
 |status=DOM
 |genus=Felis
 |species=catus<ref name="Linnaeus1758" />
 |authority=[[Carl Linnaeus|Linnaeus]], [[10th edition of Systema Naturae|1758]]<ref name="MSW3fc" />
 |synonyms=*''Catus domesticus'' {{small|[[Johann Christian Polycarp Erxleben|Erxleben]], 1777}}<ref name="Erxleben">{{Cite book |last=Erxleben |first=J. C. P. |date=1777 |title=Systema regni animalis per classes, ordines, genera, species, varietates cvm synonymia et historia animalivm. Classis I. Mammalia |location=Lipsiae |publisher=Weygandt |pages=520–521 |chapter=Felis Catus domesticus |chapter-url= https://archive.org/details/iochristpolycerx00erxl/page/520}}</ref>
* ''F. angorensis'' {{small|[[Karl Christian Gmelin|Gmelin]], 1788}}
* ''F. vulgaris'' {{small|Fischer, 1829}}
}}


Would it be prudent to propose a new site for wikitext on Area 51?

It seems a bit narrow. Why not Wikipedia as such? The homework tag Pandas now has 286,794 questions, but this is unlikely to happen for wikitext, unless some engineering school or university eyes it as a way to fight plagiarism.

There is a wikitext tag on Stack Overflow with 77 questions. Forth has more, 292 questions.

As for proposing a new site, please read the FAQ thoroughly regarding the pre-requirements: How can I propose a new site? and Changes to the Area 51 Process v3.0.

There was a proposal on Area 51 at some point (see https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/can-we-ask-any-kind-of-wiki-question-here) but that didn't go through. I would say Stack Overflow would be a natural choice, they have all kinds of questions about markup/markdown/knowledge representation formats.

Some wikitext questions are also present on [webapps.se]

Wikitext? Which one?
